# Регулярные выражения. Разбитие текста на слова. Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, split

Наткнулся на сайте на такой вот split: `split("\\\p{P}?[ \\\t\\\n\\\r]+")`.
Буду очень благодарен, за объяснение `\\p{P}?` и `\\t` метасимволов, точнее, что они значат

Comment: вы, вероятно, не поверите, но даже в википедийной статье всё это описано. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F . т.е., даже фриддла не надо читать. p.s. не `\\p`, а `\p`, и не `\\t`, а `\t`. а перед ними `\\ `

Comment: Я просто впервые столкнулся с регулярными выражениями (лабораторная работа в универе), почитал то, что нам дал препод и ничего не понял:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [`String::split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) указывается регулярное выражение для поиска разделителей, по которым будет производиться разбиение строки.

В данном случае регулярное выражение `\p{P}?[ \t\n\r]+` означает следующее:

- `\p{P}?`  - 0 или 1 [символ пунктуации](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), после которого идут
- `[ \t\n\r]+` - как минимум 1 пробельный символ, из указанных в квадратных скобках: пробел, табуляция `\t`, перевод строки `\n`, возврат каретки `\r`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!